# insert data with add previous row data in a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

May be easy way but I cant do this.I was try `sum()`in insert operation but its not working. I have table name `amount`.

```
  id      total_amount     
   1         200         
   2         400           
   3         600         
   4         800          
   5         1000
```

I want when I'll insert a value in `total_amount` it'll insert and sum previous data.
suppose if I want add `500` in total amount it'll insert `1500`.

```
  id      total_amount
   6         1500
```

if I want add `300` it insert `1800`

```
  id      total_amount
   7         1800
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to stored this data in the table rather than calculating it in a VIEW?

Comment: not VIEW. I want direct store in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an `insert` statement along with a query:

```
insert into t(id, total_amount)
    select max(id)+1, sum(total_amount) + 300
    from t;
```

This is also setting the value of `id`.  If it is `auto_increment`, then this is unnecessary.

Comment: but if I have  another column how can I insert

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `500` for instance:

```
insert into your_table (total_amount)
select sum(total_amount) + 500
from your_table
```